# adjusting the speed of movement

Tags: graphics, geometry, physics, linear-algebra

My task is to convert a movement from a straight path to a curved path.
the starting and ending points are given as well as the starting time and speed.

$ns_ at 2.000000000000 "$node_(0) setdest 90.441179033457 44.896095544010
1.373556960010"

this line above defines that node_(0) at time 2.0s starts to move toward destination (90.44, 44.89) at a speed of 1.37m/s.

[image]

I have to change the movement to be along a curved path which will be 4 movements instead of one.

[image]

I need to adjust the speed in order to get the destination of fractal path at the same time of the straight path.

I am not sure about how to get at B in fractal path at the same time of straight path?

I am thinking of calculating the time first of the straight path by the formula Time= distance/ speed. and then divide the time by 4 (cz will be 4 movements instead of one) But then I am not sure how to adjust the speed.

any ideas to help me will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the total length of the second curve, which should be (if this is the von Koch snowflake construction) 4/3 of the original curve (hence, assuming AP=PQ=QR=RB).

So your first speed should be three quarters of the speed in the second curve so that both arrive in the same time (or conversely, four third if the reference curve is the first curve).

However, since you are mentioning fractals, you should be aware that repeating the subdivision process will result in a line of infinite length : your straight path speed should be infinitely slow because it will take an infinite amount of time to follow the second path. That's when you have an infinite number of subdivisions... it will not happen in practice though :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for ur help. I am not getting what u mean by "first speed should be three quarters of the speed in the second curve" what about the other movements ? can u clarify ur solution with example dear, I did not understand it.

Comment: you said "I am not sure how to adjust the speed", so I say "the speed in your straight line should be 3/4 the speed of your subdivided line". Is-it clearer ? What do you mean by "other movements" ? The speed can be made constant (i.e., same speed) for all the 4 segments as long as your reach "B" at the same time on both curve when starting from "A" at the same time.

Comment: if the speed of the straight path is 1000m/s then the speed of the "fractal" path is 1000*4/3 m/s = 1333.3 m/s . You can use the same speed for all of the 4 movements : 1333.3 m/s to go from A to P, 1333.3 m/s to go from P to Q, 1333.3 m/s to go from Q to R, and 1333.3 m/s to go from R to B